Show that $\tilde \Omega$ is closed under addition, wedge product, and the exterior differential $d$.
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). All work is my own. This is a really simple question, but I may have mis-interpreted what it was asking.


Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth, connected manifolds and let $\pi: M \times N \rightarrow M$ be the standard projection. A tangent vector $V$ to $M \times N$ is called vertical if $\pi_* V = 0$. For any $p$-form on $M \times N$ we define the $(p-1)$-form $\iota_V \omega$ by $$ (\iota_V \omega)(x_1 , \dots , x_{p-1}) = \omega(V, x_1, \dots, x_{p-1})$$ Consider $$ \tilde \Omega =  \{ \omega \in \Omega^* (M \times N) \mid \iota_V \omega  = 0    \text{ and } \iota_V(d \omega) = 0 \text{ for all vertical vectors } V\}.$$ Show that $\tilde \Omega$ is closed under addition, wedge product, and the exterior differential $d$.

Answer: I'm having a hard time interpreting what the author wanted by "closed". This term has a rather important connotation in differential geometry: either I'm being asked if closure under an operation means that members of the set under any of the listed operations return another member of the set, or I'm being asked if all forms in the set are closed forms. Saying that $\tilde \Omega$ is closed under the exterior differential would be a massively redundant statement, so I'll take the first interpretation. That is: $$ \omega_1 + \omega _2 \in \tilde \Omega $$ and $$ \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \in \tilde \Omega$$ and $$ d \omega \in \tilde \Omega$$
First, note that for the addition of any two forms $\omega_1 + \omega_2$:
$$ \iota_ V ({\omega_1 + \omega_2}) =  (\omega_1 + \omega_2)(\cdots) = \omega_1 (\cdots) + \omega_2 (\cdots) = 0 + 0 = 0$$
Secondly, note that
$$ \iota_V ({\omega_1} \wedge {\omega_2}) = ({\omega_1} \wedge {\omega_2}) (V, \cdots) = 0$$ since this corresponds to one of the columns of the determinant being singular.
Thirdly, note that for $\omega$, $\iota_V (d\omega) = 0$ is already given. Since for any form in general, $$\iota_V (d^2 \omega) = \iota_V (0) = 0$$.

(a) Did I properly interpret what the question wanted?

Yes, you did. $\color{white}{...}$
